# Htaccess file - 404 page not found on some folders

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter and I keep having these 404 errors in my log file.

```
ERROR - 2016-04-30 16:41:15 --> 404 Page Not Found: Assets/js
ERROR - 2016-04-30 16:41:15 --> 404 Page Not Found: Assets/js
ERROR - 2016-04-30 16:41:18 --> 404 Page Not Found: Assets/js
```

So every page load causes one entry of the above error in the log file. My htaccess file looks like below. What's going wrong here?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]


    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|myadmin|robots\.txt)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

I can confirm `assets/js` are valid folders.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to get to your assets folder by going through the web path? e.g. http://localhost/assets (try to retrieve a file if you dont have indexing enabled in your webserver e.g. http://localhost/assets/css/style.css), does it load?

If this is loading you are possibly calling your assets without using a base path which means a view is trying to call directly from within its own folder.

Using site_url() is a really good step (url helper)... I urge you to make your life easier in calling assets by making a simple helper and adding it to auto load containing (something like) this:

```
if (!function_exists('assets'))
{
/**
 * Base asset directory call
 */
function assets($var)
{
    $CI =& get_instance();
    $CI->load->helper('url');

    return site_url('assets') . '/' . $var;
}
}
```

You would then call it in your view:

```
<!-- load CSS -->
<link href="<?php echo assets("css/bootstrap.min.css") ?>" rel="stylesheet">
```

It would then show this once rendered:

```
<link href="http://localhost/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

This is just a really basic example though, if you have heaps of assets to call in a header or footer, I would suggest creating a helper to load based on a config file, you can also specify what is required on certain page loads that way as well so its dynamically loaded with a foreach.

Also do be careful calling Assets (capital letter) vs assets (no capital letter) is very different, many webservers are case-sensitive...

I run the following for my htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: hi thanks for your answer. Yes I am able to access assets folder directly (after disabling default directory index). Yes I have references to /assets/css/styles.css or /assets/js/filename.js etc in my view files without base url. However, I don't think that's the main issue? I tried putting the base_url to these references but it didnt seem to have helped???

Comment: When I view source of my webpage all the references to /assets/js are now with base url and I still get two error logs entries in my log files for Assets/js not found??

Comment: I added my htaccess file that works no problems, I think maybe " RewriteBase /" might cause an issue too, consider removing that as a first step

Comment: I suggest browsing around your site with developer console enabled and open to the 'network' tab, see which exact files in which controller/view are not able to be found, this will tell you also which assets are unable to be found (spelling mistakes, old files not used). Failing that searching all of your files for 'Assets/js' links and finding the usages and ensure correct